# Paginacion si esta, pero no se muestra en un 100% tamaño de pantalla predeterminado

Tags: java, paginación

Tengo una paginacion para que se muestre de 10 en 10, y el problema que tengo es que en el 100% de la pagina no aparece.

Asi se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio si reduzco el tamaño de la pagina, ahí esta, pero en un 100% que es lo predeterminado, no lo hace.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la function para paginar:

```
function paginar(paginas)
{

    $('#pagination').bootpag({
        total: paginas,
        page: 1,
        maxVisible: 10,
        first: '←',
        last: '→',
        wrapClass: 'pagination',
        activeClass: 'active',
        disabledClass: 'disabled',
        nextClass: 'next',
        prevClass: 'prev',
        lastClass: 'last',
        firstClass: 'first'
    }).on("page", function(event, num)
    {
      var elements = numberElements * num;
      elements = elements - numberElements;
      pagina = elements;

      globalCounter = (num * numberElements) - (numberElements);

      if (globalSearch == "undefined")
      {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost/WareHouse/apis/receipt.php?elements="+elements+"&numberElements="+numberElements,
          type: "GET",
          success: function(data)
          {
            showReceipt(data);

          }
        });
      }
      else
      {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost/WareHouse/apis/receipt.php?search="+globalSearch+"&elements="+elements+"&numberElements="+numberElements,
          type: "GET",
          success:function(data)
          {
            showReceipt(data);

          }
        });
      }

    });
}
```

Aqui es donde mando a llamar la function:

```
    contarArticulos = JSONdata.total;
    contarArticulos = contarArticulos / numberElements;

    var int = Math.trunc(contarArticulos) + ".0";
    var pages;

    if (contarArticulos % 1 == 0)
    {
        paginas = int;
    }
    else
    {
        paginas =  Math.trunc(contarArticulos) + 1;
    }

//Usado para volver a crear la paginacion dependiendo si se esta filtrando o no
switch (filtrado)
{
    //Si es uno es que se acaba de iniciar la pagina
    case 1:
        paginar(paginas);
        filtrado = 2;
        break;
    //Si es tres es que se va a realizar un filtrado
    case 3:
        paginar(paginas);
        filtrado = 2;
    break;
    case 4:
        $('#pagination').bootpag({total: paginas, maxVisible: 10, page: 1});
        filtrado = 2;
        break;
    }
```

**Nota:** Este mismo código lo he usado para otras partes del proyecto es exactamente lo mismo, pero solo sucede eso en este.

Alguien sabe porque ocurre esto?